# C Invalid read from valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

I have an invalid read of size 1 exception in my C file program. I get the following from valgrind:

```
==9072== Invalid read of size 1
==9072==    at 0x4C28FB2: __GI_strlen (mc_replace_strmem.c:404)
==9072==    by 0x401FA8: getJsonRecord (in /.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/csd92/Systems_Programming/Indexer/index)
==9072==    by 0x401CF3: jsonWrite (in /.autofs/ilab/ilab_users/csd92/Systems_Programming/Indexer/index)
==9072==    by 0x400BFC: main (index.c:42)
==9072==  Address 0x51d6e80 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 19 free'd
==9072==    at 0x4C27430: free (vg_replace_malloc.c:446)
==9072==    by 0x400F65: file_handler (index.c:110)
==9072==    by 0x400DBB: directory_handle (index.c:82)
==9072==    by 0x400DDC: directory_handle (index.c:84)
==9072==    by 0x400BC3: main (index.c:34)
```

Define :

```
#define trailing_record() ("},\n\0")
#define not_trailing_record() ("}\n\0")
#define record_first() ("\t\t{\"")
#define record_second() ("\" :")
```

This is my getJsonRecord:

```
char * getJsonRecord (char * token, char * frequency, int trailing) 
{

  if(token == 0 || frequency == 0)
  {
    return "Token or frequency == 0";
  }

  char * entry = 0;
  entry = calloc((strlen(token) + strlen(frequency) +30),1);

  int tokensize= strlen (token);
  int freqsize = strlen(frequency);

  strcat(entry,record_first());
  strcat(entry,token);
  strcat(entry,record_second());
  strcat(entry,frequency);

  if(trailing == 0)
  {
   strcat(entry,not_trailing_record());
  } 

  else
  {
    strcat(entry,trailing_record());
  }

  free(frequency);
  return entry;

}
```

These are the values getting passed to getJsonRecord when it fails:

```
token Index_Test/3:29:16, frequency 3 trailing 0
token Index_Test/Temp/cable21.txt, frequency 1 trailing 1
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Looks like whatever you passed for `token` or `frequency` has already been free()'d at `index.c:110`

Comment: `getJsonRecord` did not allocate `frequency` so it *probably* should not be freeing it either.  However, this might not be your actual bug.  The actual bug is just as likely to be in code you have not shown.  Please read and follow the instructions at https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: On the face of it, one of `token` or `frequency` is pointing at recently freed memory — and therefore you should not still be reading from it.  It's hard to say which.

Comment: Okay. Thank you guys... @RyanHaining you were right. I see my error

Comment: Frankly, the computation `if(trailing == 0){
   entry = calloc((strlen(token) + strlen(frequency) +30),1);
  }else {
   entry = calloc((strlen(token) + strlen(frequency) +31),1);
  }` could be written to use just the longer string size; the one 'wasted' byte is unlikely to be significant.

Comment: It may also be that a never-initialized pointer was passed to either `token` or `frequency`.  The value of such a pointer is not necessarily `NULL`.

Comment: before using a pointer returned from the memory allocation functions: (malloc, calloc, realloc), always check (!=NULL) to assure the operation was successful.

Comment: for ease of readability and understanding by us humans: 1) separate code blocks (for, if, else, while, do...while, switch, case, default) via a blank line. 2) a 2 char indent width is not visible when using variable width fonts,  Suggest using 4 spaces. Never use tabs.  3) consistently indent the code,  Indent after every opening brace '{'.  unindent before every closing brace '}'.

Comment: these kind of line combinations: `char * trailing = "}\n\0";
      strcat(entry,trailing);`  are better written as: `strcat(entry, "}\n\0" );   and would be even better if using: `#define trailing()  ("}\n\0")`  then the original call to `strcat()` can be used, `strcat( entry, trailing ); Then nothing is placed on the stack,  All the work is performed at compile time rather than run time and the call to `strcat()` is well documented

Comment: @user3629249 updated. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ryan Haining was correct, sometimes my token was already freed in a conditional loop which I never thought would get called before the file was written.

The conditional loop before being fixed :

```
if(filepath_index == (filepath_count))
{

    char ** temp = malloc(filepath_count *2 * sizeof(char *));

    int i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < filepath_count; i ++){
        temp[i] = malloc(strlen(filepaths[i])+1);
        strcpy(temp[i],filepaths[i]);
        free(filepaths[i]);
    }

    free(filepaths);
    filepaths = temp;
    filepath_count = filepath_count * 2;
}
```

The conditional loop after being fixed:
if(filepath_index == (filepath_count))
{

```
char ** temp = malloc(filepath_count *2 * sizeof(char *));
int i = 0;

for (i = 0; i < filepath_count; i ++){
    temp[i] = filepaths[i];
}

free(filepaths);
filepaths = temp;
filepath_count = filepath_count * 2;
}
```